# How to access entries in Web Config from Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have a file called Dashboard.xaml in an Silverlight Project. The Dashboard.xaml has a link called LinkA that I want to show only to certain users. If I store the list of allowed users in Web Config seperated by commas, how can I access it in the Silverlight Project.

What I basically want to do is get the list of allowed users and toggle the visibility of the LinkA in Dashboard.xaml file.

Thanks in advance for your ideas and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

you cant do it directly--the web.config is server side and Silverlight is client side.

Now, that said, you CAN send values to your silverlight app on the aspx page via initparams.  [here is an article to show the way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/luc/archive/2009/05/29/reading-web-config-parameters-from-a-silverlight-application.aspx).